# Which upgrade path for banana farm is better? Left or Right?

Tags: bloons-td-5

I know that the left hand side upgrade for banana farm is the research facility which produces a lot of bananas while the investment bank gives interest. So, which one is more cost-efficient given very little space in the map? I'm going for approximately 100 rounds or so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the situation.

The 2|4 farm is cheaper, and can be bought and paid back sooner. In fact, it's $7500 cheaper than a 4|2. It produces $1180 each round with a 20% interest rate after the round, which is a little bit more than half what the 4|2 produces, but, after 7 rounds after acquisition (assuming you haven't withdrawn) it will have payed itself back and produce $2300. The 2|4 will pay for itself sooner, however, the funds are not as sufficient as the 4|2.

The 4|2 farm is a lot more expensive, and cannot be paid back as fast, but if it is purchased early on, it can have a positive effect on gameplay. After the same 7 rounds, it will be $2400 short of paying itself back, but it produces a constant $3000 each round wich quickly adds up and will be very beneficial for late-round gameplay.

In short, The 2|4 farm is for short term investments, and the 4|2 farm is for long term investments. The 2|4 will produce some quickly, the 4|2 will produce more after a longer period of time. I *personally* prefer the 2|4, but this site is for answers, not discussions.

Comment: I actually did this test way back in August 2017. I was curious for which one to use, so I recorded as much information as I could and found this information. I hope this answers your question, and I'm glad I could share my research that has been on my computer for months.

Answer (score 2):

[This is the math that you are looking for.](http://bloons.wikia.com/wiki/Banana_Farm)

Essentially the answer to your question is, it depends. If you are looking for a quick return on your money *soon*, go plantation. If you are looking for the most money *at some point* , go with bank.

Space on the map doesn't matter, they take up the same space regardless of upgrades.

Comment: Research gives you more money.  The Revnue % is lower, but the cost is so much higher that a lower percentage actually gives you higher return.  Research is what you want for long term, not Bank.

Answer (score 2):

Bank is the better option overall. It pays for itself faster and is consistent money. If you go Research, you still have to click on each box of bananas it throws out, or you don't get paid. The later rounds (100+) require a lot of active play from the player, i.e., you can't just sit and watch things happen; you will absolutely have to be activating abilities, so you won't have much time to click banana crates or even notice them.

It realistically takes too long for research to actually pay off, and even then, you must be focused on those towers to get the full payoff.

Comment: Hi bobpants, we don't have necro's here, because this is not a forum, but a Q&A site. (Good) answers are always welcome, no matter how old the question :)